# Wordpress shortcodes working in php but not in text editor

Tags: wordpress

I seem to be having a problem outputting shortcodes from the wordpress text editor. The shortcodes work fine when echoing from php but it is only in the text editor they simply produce what is written.

I have added the following lines to my functions.php:

```
 add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
  add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

But this has no effect. This is happening across multiple plugins. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved this. I figured out that this was only happening on custom templates. I then queried that issue and found that you have to use the_content() function to extract the content within your custom template and have shortcodes work. This is because the_content() parses the content in a manner that will make your shortcodes work.